# What's the best way to center horizontally and vertically the play SVG in the middle?

Tags: html, center

I know there are a whole bunch of different ways to do this, I'm looking for the best and simplest way to accomplish this.

All I'm looking for is the most reliable way to center horizontally and vertically the play svg in the middle.

All help doing this would be greatly appreciated.

**I was just given this piece of code, but I don't know how to use it.**

Can someone show me please?

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;

  margin: -70px 0 0 -170px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zLtk9n4p/

[image]

```
<div id="playButton2" style="display:block; width: 266px; height: 266px; cursor: pointer;background-color: #000000 ;background-image: linear-gradient( to right,transparent 83px,#0059dd 83px, #0059dd 86px, transparent 86px, transparent  174px, #0059dd 174px, #0059dd 177px, transparent 177px ); border: 3px solid #0059dd;"

onclick=" 
        var button = document.getElementById('playButton2');
        var player = document.getElementById('player2');
          document.querySelector('#playButton2 .initial').style.display='none';
          document.querySelector('#playButton2 .speaker').style.display='none';
          document.querySelector('#playButton2 .play').style.display='none';
        player.volume=1.0; if (player.paused) {
        playButton2.style.border='3px solid #e77d19';
        playButton2.style.background = 'linear-gradient( to right,transparent 83px,#e77d19 83px, #e77d19 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #e77d19 174px, #e77d19 177px, transparent 177px ), url(\'http://via.placeholder.com/260x260\')';
        playButton2.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
        playButton2.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
        playButton2.style.backgroundPosition = 'center'; 
        document.querySelector('#playButton2 .pause').style.display='inline-block';
        document.querySelector('#playButton2 .play').style.display='none';
        player.play();
        } else {
        playButton2.style.border='3px solid #e77d19';
        playButton2.style.background = 'linear-gradient( to right,transparent 83px,#e77d19 83px, #e77d19 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #e77d19 174px, #e77d19 177px, transparent 177px ), url(\'http://via.placeholder.com/260x260\')';
        playButton2.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';    
        playButton2.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
        playButton2.style.backgroundPosition = 'center'; 
        document.querySelector('#playButton2 .pause').style.display='none';
        document.querySelector('#playButton2 .play').style.display='inline-block';
        player.pause();
        }"onmouseover="
var player = document.getElementById('player2');
player.isPlaying = function () {
    return player.paused === false;
}
if  (player.isPlaying()) {
  document.querySelector('#playButton2 .speaker').style.display='none';
  document.querySelector('#playButton2 .pause').style.display='inline-block';
}"

onmouseout="
var player = document.getElementById('player2');
player.isPlaying = function () {
    return player.paused === false;
}
if  (player.isPlaying()) {
  document.querySelector('#playButton2 .pause').style.display='none';
  document.querySelector('#playButton2 .speaker').style.display='inline-block';
}">

  <svg class="initial" width="90" height="108" viewbox="0 -10 85 120">
    <path fill="currentColor" style="stroke: #e77d19; stroke-width:3px;color:black; " d="M81 44.6c5 3 5 7.8 0 10.8L9 98.7c-5 3-9 .7-9-5V6.3c0-5.7 4-8 9-5l72 43.3z"></path>
  </svg>

  <svg class="pause" style="display: none;" width="90" height="108" viewbox="-13 -10 85 120">
    <path fill="currentColor" style="stroke: #e77d19; stroke-width:3px;color:transparent;" d="M0 8c0-5 3-8 8-8s9 3 9 8v84c0 5-4 8-9 8s-8-3-8-8V8zm43 0c0-5 3-8 8-8s8 3 8 8v84c0 5-3 8-8 8s-8-3-8-8V8z"></path>
  </svg>

  <svg class="speaker" style="display: none;" width="60" height="72" viewbox="0 0 16 14">
    <path d="M12.945.38l-.652.762c1.577 1.462 2.57 3.544 2.57 5.858 0 2.314-.994 4.396-2.57 5.858l.65.763c1.79-1.644 2.92-3.997 2.92-6.62S14.735 2.024 12.945.38zm-2.272 2.66l-.65.762c.826.815 1.34 1.947 1.34 3.198 0 1.25-.515 2.382-1.342 3.2l.652.762c1.04-1 1.69-2.404 1.69-3.96 0-1.558-.65-2.963-1.69-3.963zM0 4v6h2.804L8 13V1L2.804 4H0zm7-1.268v8.536L3.072 9H1V5h2.072L7 2.732z"
    fill="#1ed760 " fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
  </svg>

  <svg class="play" style="display: none;" width="90" height="108" viewbox="0 -10 85 120">
    <path fill="currentColor" style="stroke: #e77d19; stroke-width:3px;color:transparent; " d="M81 44.6c5 3 5 7.8 0 10.8L9 98.7c-5 3-9 .7-9-5V6.3c0-5.7 4-8 9-5l72 43.3z"></path>
  </svg>


</div>

<audio id="player2" style="display:none;">
  <source src='' type='audio/mpeg'></source>
</audio>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use these styles:

```
#playButton2 {
  position: relative;
}

div#playButton2 > svg {
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way would be to use flex box. Change the display property of the button to flex

```
<div id="playButton2" style="display:flex; ...
```

and give svg initial margin: auto

```
<svg class="initial" style="margin: auto" ...
```

It will now align to the center.

But note that flex box is whole different way of creating mark up and you might experience some unexpected behavior when you use flex box instead of display block instead, but for vertical alignment flex box is certainly the most reliable way.